# WSUS: organize computers

Tags: wsus, organizational-unit

in my 2012R2 domain I need to organize efficiently clients and servers in WSUS. Who setup the domain created one group for each location, and each one is divided into operating systems:

```
Location 1
----Clients
----------- Win Vista
----------- Win 7
----------- Win 8
----Servers
----------- Win 2008R2
------------Win 2012

Location 2
----Clients
----------- Win Vista
----------- Win 7
----------- Win 8
----Servers
----------- Win 2008R2
------------Win 2012
```

I noticed that servers are assigned to multiple folders, for example Exchange server is assigned to Location1,Servers,Win 2012. The first question is if this kind of assignment is correct or if I should assign an entity only to the last folder in the tree.
Then, my principal goal is to group by update behavior: in AD I have two groups of computers and with GPO I deploy two kind of update: one is "Automatically download and notify of installation", the other is "Automatic download and scheduled installation". But I want the computer with the second policy to set a deadline, so normal users can delay the installation but after one week they have to install updates. Final questions are: 1) is my AD environment correct to reach my goal? 2) how can I efficiently organize my computers in order to have a hierarchical organization and reach the deadline goal? If I'm not wrong I would have to assign computer to the AD group AND to assign it to the correct WSUS group AND set the deadline when approving updates. Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You already have a GPO for your different update settings.

Within these GPO's you can enable [Client-Side Targeting](http://prajwaldesai.com/how-to-configure-client-side-targeting-in-wsus/) to move all PC's in one GPO to a Computer Group in WSUS.

Is this what you are looking for?